# Draw this fractal generated by applying Newton's method to cosh(x) - 1

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, kolmogorov-complexity, graphical-output, fractal

I came across this picture the other day: (Credit to Josep M Batlle I Ferrer)

[image: N(f(x)=cosh(x)-1)]

Your job is to generate this picture. This graph is generated by repeatedly applying newton's method to the graph of:

$$f(x)=\cosh(x)-1$$

In other words, repeatedly apply the following function to every point till the rectangular distance is less than some limit to a attractor:

$$g(x)=\frac{x \cdot \sinh(x) - \cosh(x) + 1}{\sinh(x)}$$

The process is described in psuedocode below:

```
let n be the maximum number of iterations
for every point (as a complex number) in the image:
    repeat n times:
        point = (point * sinh(point) - cosh(point) + 1) / sinh(point)
        
        if the rectangular distance between the point and any attractor is less than 0.01:
             break
        end if
    end repeat
    color the point in the image depending on the nearest attractor and the number of iterations required
```

The rectangular distance is defined as `max(abs(dx), abs(dy))`. We use rectangular distance instead of straight line distance so we get the wave shapes that make this graph so beautiful.

There is a attractor at `0+n*2i*PI` for any integer N. Thus at even increments of 2 PI in the imaginary direction.

## Rules

- Your graph must include the area from `[-0.75, -0.75 + PI]` to `[0.75, +0.75 + PI]`.
- Resolution over this needs to be at least 256 by 256. Either characters or pixels. If you decide to cover a larger area you need to increase the resolution in proportion.
- Use at least 20 iterations.
- Both adjacent iteration counts and adjacent attractors need to be drawn in distinct colors. You must use at least 3 different colors. Coloring should soley be based on the attractor and iteration count.
- If any point causes a division by 0 or another math error, you may choose to render anything at this point. This is considered undefined behavior.
- Displaying a image, saving a image, or drawing ASCII art are all acceptable, as long as the other rules are met. If you draw ASCII art characters need to be ANSI colored.
- Please include a screenshot of the result in your answer

This is code golf, shortest answer wins. ASCII art answers *do not* compete against graphical answers in the same language.

## Background info

- [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method)
- [Newton's fractal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton_fractal)
- [Hyperbolic Trignometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_functions)
- [Julia set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julia_set)

Comment: Is the definition of \$g(x)\$ supposed to have \$\sinh(x)\$ on the bottom? If not, what is \$pos\$?

Comment: @Zionmyceliaadamancy fixed, thanks

Answer (score 12):

## [Desmos](https://desmos.com/calculator), <s>401</s> <s>375</s> <s>357</s> 353 bytes

-26 bytes thanks to [@aiden-chow](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/96039/aiden-chow)

-18 bytes thanks to [flexabrotnt#1409](https://discordapp.com/users/339104210194792459)

```
H(u,v)=(u.xv.x-v.yu.y,u.xv.y+v.xu.y)
F(u,v)=(u.xv.x+u.yv.y,u.yv.x-u.xv.y)/(v.x²+v.y²)
E(z)=e^{z.x}(cos(z.y),sin(z.y))
C(z,k)=H((1/2,0),E(z)+kE(H((-1,0),z)))
N(z)=F(H(z,C(z,-1))-C(z,1)+(1,0),C(z,-1))
G(z)=max(z.x²,z.y²)
Y(z)=N(N(N(N(N(z)))))
Z(z)=Y(Y(Y(Y(z))))
l=[0...2]
O=hsv(l110,1,1)
P=Z((x,y))
X=round(P.y/(2π))
G((0,2Xπ)-P)<0.01\{\mod(X,3)=l\}
```

[Try It On Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/uskzayywop)

[Before golfing](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/aei4dlbu0i)
[image: Rendered in desmos]

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice answer!

Comment: @NoHaxJustRadvylf Thank you!

Comment: Amazing answer! I’m achow on discord; this is my code golf account.

Comment: @AidenChow 
wow your profile shows you are "top %2" this year. congratulations:)

Comment: I don't see the number of iterations visible in the output

Comment: @mousetail It’s 20 iterations, you can tell by the `Y` and `Z` functions, amounting to a total of 20 recursive calls to `N`.

Comment: The entire red area at the bottom seems to be the exact same color, even though some areas should require less iterations than others

Comment: This is amazing but it seems to be 355 bytes ([count with this](https://mothereff.in/byte-counter))

Comment: @Steffan Fixed it, thanks.

Answer (score 7):

## Python + Pygame, <del>410</del> 392 bytes (Example Submission)

*-16 bytes thanks to wizzwizz4 and others*

```py
from pygame import*
from cmath import*
w=256;s=Surface((w,w));f=lambda p:p-(cosh(p)-1)/sinh(p);g=lambda t:round(t.imag/pi/2)*pi*2j;h=lambda p:max(abs(p.real),abs(p.imag))>0.01
for x in range(w):
 for y in range(w):
  t=x/w-0.5+(y/w-0.5-pi)*1j
  for i in range(99):
   try:t=f(t);1/h(g(t)-t)
   except:break
  s.set_at((x,y),[0,[w-1,5,5],[9,w-1,9]][(round(t.imag/pi/2)+i)%3])
image.save(s,"f")
```

Result will be saved as a TGA file named `"f"`:

[image]

Comment: Do you need to save as a file with a ".png" extension?

Comment: I think the three lines in the middle can be replaced by `try:t=f(t);1/(h(g(t)-t)>=0.01)` // `except:break`.

Comment: @emanresuA I think .png is one of the shortest extensions that can be used? The save method needs ab extension to know what format to save the image in.

Comment: You can shave two bytes off that if you put the comparison into h, so you don't need the parens.

Comment: `import*` is valid syntax

Comment: Running with `save(s,"f")` works. `$ file f` -> `f: Targa image data - RGB - RLE 256 x 256 x 24 - top`.

Comment: @GammaFunction Saving without extension in pygame is platform dependent. It works about half the time. I guess that's good enough for code golf though.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 wow abusing the 0 division is  a 1000 IQ move thanks

Comment: Those spaces around the `=` in `t = f(t)` don't need to be there. Also, the explanation is slightly out of date – and I suspect that `>0.01` might make a different image to `>=0.01` by a few pixels.

Answer (score 7):

## Rust + [Num](https://autumnai.github.io/cuticula/num/index.html) ASCII Art - <del>420</del> 413 bytes

*-6 bytes thanks to @LF*

```rs
use{num::complex::*,std::f32::consts::*};(0..255).any(|y|(0..512).any(|x|if let Some(n)=(0..99).scan(Complex::new(x as f32/256.0-1.,y as f32/256.0-0.5+PI),|s,l|{*s=*s-(s.cosh()-1.)/s.sinh();Some((*s,l))}).filter(|s|s.0.re.abs().max(s.0.im-((s.0.im/(2.*PI)).round()*2.*PI).abs())<0.01).next(){print!("\x1b[{:0<2};{:0<2}m0",30+n.1%8,40+((n.0.im/PI/2. + 36.).round()%8.)as usize)}else{print!("0")}>())||print!("
")>());
```

[image]

Comment: `use{num_complex::*,std::f32::consts::*};` (using the `num-complex` crate directly instead of `num`)

Comment: `.filter(...).next()` => `.find(...)`. `*s=*s-...` => `*s-=...`. `print!("\n")` => `println!()`.

Comment: Can `s.0.re.abs().max(s.0.im-((s.0.im/(2.*PI)).round()*2.*PI).abs())<0.01` be shortened to something like `s.0.re.abs()<0.01&&s.0.im.cos()>0.01.cos()` using the observation from my answer? (I don't speak Rust.)

Answer (score 5):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>271</s> <s>260</s> <s>253</s> 251 bytes

```js
c=>{z=c.getContext`2d`;for(i=384;i--;)for(j=384;i--;)with(Math){x=i/256-.75;y=j/256-.75+PI;for(k=10;k<30>(x*x<1e-4&abs(y-2*PI*(v=round(y/2/PI)))<.01);k++)w=cosh(x)+cos(y),x-=sinh(x)/w,y-=sin(y)/w;z.fillStyle=`#0${(k+v%10)*3%10}9`;z.fillRect(i,j,1,1)}}
```

Takes as parameter a 384×384 canvas on which to draw the result. Demo, with whitespace for readability and animation:

```js
f = async c => {
  z = c.getContext`2d`;
  for (i = 384; i--; ) {
    for (j = 384; j--; ) with (Math) {
      x = i / 256 - .75;
      y = j / 256 - .75 + PI;
      for (k = 10; k < 30 > (x * x < 1e-4 & abs(y - 2 * PI * (v = round(y / 2 / PI))) < .01); k++)
        w = cosh(x) + cos(y),
        x -= sinh(x) / w,
        y -= sin(y) / w;
      z.fillStyle = `#0${(k+v%10)*3%10}9`;
      z.fillRect(i, j, 1, 1);
    }
    await new Promise(resolve => requestAnimationFrame(resolve));
  }
};
f(c);
```

```html
<canvas width=384 height=384 id=c>
```

Edit: Saved 11 bytes thanks to @Ausername. Saved 7 bytes thanks to @Steffan. Saved 2 bytes thanks to @Dingus.

Comment: You can save a few bytes by making the color `\`#${k%10}8f\``. It actually looks better too!

Comment: Also (general tip) you can save a few bytes in the for loops by `++i<384` or similar

Comment: @emanresuA I chose a slightly different palette as I didn't like that one, but thanks for the approach.

Comment: @emanresuA I do need to have the correct values inside the loops though, so you'd need to explain how to achieve that.

Comment: `i=0;i<384;i++` => `i=384;i--;`, and same with `j`

Comment: also you can remove the space at `round(y/2 /PI)`

Comment: @Steffan Thanks, that makes much more sense. Also I can't believe I missed a space, d'oh!

Comment: `abs(x)<.01&&abs(y-2*PI*round(y/2/PI))<.01` can be `x**2<1e-4&&cos(y)>cos(.01)` (see my answer).

Comment: @Dingus even `x*x` works, and `.99`or `.99` should work in place of cos(.1)

Comment: Hey, seems like you don't color adjacent attractors differently, which is a requirement. Good answer otherwise though.

Comment: @emanresuA cos(.1) = sqrt(1-sin(.1)**2) ~ sqrt(1-.1**2) = sqrt(.99) ~ 1.99/2 = .995 (and you wanted cos(.01) ~ .99995 anyway)

Comment: @mousetail Sorry for not noticing, should be fixed now.

Comment: @Dingus Sadly it turns out that I need the value of `round(y/2/PI)`...

Answer (score 4):

## [Pyxplot 0.8.4](http://pyxplot.org.uk/), <sup><s>190</s> <s>188</s></sup> 186 bytes

```
se nu c
su g(x,y){z=x+y*i
fo n=1to20{z=z-coth(z)+csch(z)
if(Re(z)**2<1e-4)*cos(Im(z))>cos(.01){ret ceil(Im(z)/pi-.5);}
}
}
se sa gr 1e3x1e3
se colm hsb c2:c1:1
p[-1:1][2:4]g(x,y):n w col
```

Conveniently for code golf, most commands in Pyxplot may be abbreviated zealously. By default (empty `.pyxplotrc` config file), output is written to `pyxplot.eps`.

[image]

If the text and axis labels produced by default must be removed, replace the last line with

```
se ax xy in
p[-1:1][2:4]g(x,y):n t''w col
```

at a cost of 15 bytes. Add `se s s` for a square aspect ratio.

Some mathematical simplifications are used. Firstly, we write \$g\$ as \$g(z) = z-\coth(z)+\mathop{\rm csch}(z)\$. Secondly, we note that \$\max(\lvert\Delta x\rvert, \lvert\Delta y \rvert) < t\$ implies that both \$\lvert\Delta x\rvert < t\$ and \$\lvert\Delta y\rvert < t\$ and treat these two constraints separately:

- \$\lvert\Delta x\rvert = \lvert x-0\rvert = \lvert x\rvert\$, so the first constraint becomes \$x^2<t^2\$, which is shorter in Pyxplot than \$\lvert x\rvert < t\$ (which would be `abs(Re(z))<.01`).
- \$\lvert\Delta y\rvert = \lvert y-2k\pi\rvert\$ for some integer \$k\$. Observe that the attractors lie at points where the cosine function is maximal, i.e. \$\cos(2k\pi)=1\$. Thus the constraint on \$y\$ may be written as \$\cos(\lvert y-2k\pi\rvert) > \cos(t)\$, which simplifies to \$\cos(y) > \cos(t)\$ by the symmetry and periodicity of the cosine function.

For the plot, an HSB colourmap is used. At each point the hue is determined by the number of iterations (`n` in the code), automatically rescaled to span the range from 0 and 1 (i.e. the full range of hues). The saturation is determined by the value of \$2k\$ (the return value of `g(x,y)`) for the point's attractor, again rescaled to span the full range of saturations. The brightness is fixed at maximum.

An iteration limit of 20 is imposed. Red and orange hues become more predominant at the expense of green and blue as this limit is increased.

In theory, it is possible to omit `[-1:1][2:4]` in the last line of the code (saving 10 bytes), have Pyxplot apply its default axis ranges (\$-10\le x,y\le 10\$), and increase the grid resolution (`1e3x1e3`) to compensate. In practice, setting the resolution to `4e3x4e3` exhausted the available memory (16 GB RAM plus 20 GB swap) on my machine.

#### Ungolfed code

```
set numerics complex
subroutine g(x, y) {
  z = x + y * i
  for n = 1 to 20 {
    z = z - coth(z) + csch(z)
    if Re(z)**2 < 1e-4 and cos(Im(z)) > cos(1e-2) {
      return ceil(Im(z) / pi - 0.5)
    }
  }
}
set samples grid 1e3 x 1e3
set colourmap hsb c2:c1:1
plot [-1:1] [2:4] g(x, y):n with colourmap
```

Comment: The difference in shading between attractors is very subtle but it counts

Comment: Thank you for introducing me to pyxplot

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 128 bytes

```
Image@Table[n=0;x+y*I//.z_/;Max@Abs@{Re@z,Mod[i=Im@z,Pi,n+=8t;-1]}>2t:>z-Coth@z+Csch@z;i~Hue~n,{y,-1+Pi,1+Pi,t=.005},{x,-1,1,t}]
```

[image]